# Codesynthesis can't parse xs:anyType c++

Tags: c++, xml, xsd, codesynthesis

My xsd element is

```
<xs:complexType name="timeseries">
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="start-date" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
  <xs:element name="step-duration" type="xs:int"/>
  <xs:element name="value" type="xs:anyType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xs:sequence>
```

Although i can't parse this using codesynthecis in C++ using VS2010. Is there any property of the XSD during compile which allows the xs:anyType parsing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I have downloaded the latest release which has an option `--generate AnyType` I couldn't get the data. Unfortunately I had to change the XSD and now I have different sequences with different types (xs:boolean,xs:float, etc) depending on the data.